# CloudKit notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I might be missing something obvious here.

How would one create a CloudKit notification with detail about the CKRecord that you are being notified about? (i.e. not just a generic "New Item Created!" but a notification with the title of the record for instance, like, "Jill and Jessica's Birthday Party!")

Is the proper way to do this to create a new subscription with a new notification.alertBody for every new record change? That doesn't make any sense.

That leaves the option queryNotification.recordID to pull the data out of CloudKit (or my local store) and add it to the notification somehow? What's the method for adding or changing the values of an already notified notification? What am I missing?

Updated: Per Edwin's suggestion here's a code snippet, but it doesn't work.

```
let notification = CKNotificationInfo()
notification.alertBody = "Added: %@" as NSString
notification.alertLocalizationArgs = ["name"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just fill the .alertLocalizationArgs of the CKNotificationInfo object

The documentation for the .alertLocalizationArgs says:

> Use of this property is optional. This property contains an array of
>   NSString objects, each of which corresponds to a field of the record
>   that triggered the push notification. Those names are used to retrieve
>   the corresponding values from the record. The values are then used to
>   replace any substitution variables in either the alertBody or
>   alertLocalizationKey strings. The values themselves must be NSString,
>   NSNumber, or NSDate objects. Do not specify keys with other values.
>   String values that are greater than 100 characters in length may be
>   truncated when added to the push notification.
>
> If you use %@ for your substitution variables, those variables are
>   replaced by walking the array in order. If you use variables of the
>   form %n$@, where n is an integer, n represents the index (starting at
>   1) of the item in the array to use. Thus, the first item in the array
>   replaces the variable %1$@, the second item replaces the variable
>   %2$@, and so on. You can use indexed substitution variables to change
>   the order of items in the resulting string, which might be necessary
>   when you localize your app’s messages.

Here are 2 samples of how I use it:

```
            notificationInfo.alertBody = "%1$@ : %2$@"
            notificationInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = ["FromName", "Text"]
```

And the 2nd sample:

```
            notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "News: %1$@"
            notificationInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = ["Subject"]
```

Where you have the "News: %1$@" as a key in the Localizable.strings file

Update: It looks like you now require to use the .alertLocalizationKey. So the first sample does not work anymore.

Comment: Ok. I've tried this but can't seem to get this to work. Is there a different id besides %@ inside the string I should be using for swift code? My notification just repeats the string "Added: %@" and doesnt replace with my record data.

Comment: If you want to see a complete code where its functioning, then have a look at: https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao

Comment: Make sure you delete your old subscription first before creating a new one with different settings

Comment: Yup that seemed to be the issue. I deleted all subscriptions and now is working. Thanks!

Comment: Your first example with just the alertBody doesn't work for me.  However when I added the localizable file and used the alert localization key, then it worked.

Comment: if you started use `CKSubscription` with a specific `CKNotificationInfo`, and you change `CKNotificationInfo`  attributes in *Production environment**, then you will have to create new container

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to just remove the subscription?

Comment: Is it possible to send down dynamic localized strings? For example if I want to send a notification "Backup your data" in English and French, are there ways to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see the 2nd sample from the answer. The translations do have to be pressen in your .strings file in your app.